# What is the benefit of using TVITEMEX instead of TVITEM structure?

Tags: mfc

I have read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-getitem) which states:

> Pointer to a `TVITEM` structure that specifies the information to retrieve and receives information about the item. With version 4.71 and later, you can use a `TVITEMEX` structure instead.

But what real benefit is there in your application? I have always used `TVITEM` if I needed to use `GetItem` and `SetItem`.

Comment: How else would you be able to apply the `TVIS_EX_DISABLED` or `TVIS_EX_FLAT` states?

Comment: @AdrianMole Ah, I see a `SetItemStateEx` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctreectrl-class?view=msvc-160&redirectedfrom=MSDN#setitemstateex Thanks for clearing it up.